# How do I remove the default limit from pokemon api?

Tags: ajax, pokeapi

I have been having trouble getting to return any pokemon that is currently registered in pokeapi. Currently when the pokemon is returned that is #'d over 20 it wont return any value. Yet, if bulbasaur (or any in the first 20) is searched data will return. Not sure how to remove the limiter. I thought of using a for of method to search for user input and have an ajax run twice essentially

```
//getNationalDex();
//you can replace console.log with render(data.results) here to pushh the info to the next function console.log(data)
function getNationalDex(event) {
  event.preventDefault(); //allows mee to stop the submit button from functioning  for example
  userInput = $input.val(); //get value from the input on the textbox
  if (userInput === "") return;
  $input.val("");//starts with a blank input i believe 
  $.ajax(nationalDex + userInput) //gets url and adds the userinput
    // nationalDex.innerHtml(+'')
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(data); //    render(data.results)
        $pokemon.text(data.name);
      // $moveSet.text(data.moves[0]);
      for (const move of data.moves ){ //iterates over moveset array in api 
       $("<p>", { // this creates a new <p> for every move in the array 
         id: "move",
         class: "moves",
       })
         .text(move.move.name)
         .appendTo($moveSet);
      };
        // $type.text(data.type[0],[0]);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
  //   function render(pokemon) {
  //     //
}
```

Comment: You can change the per-page limit, but you'll probably have to deal with pagination. https://pokeapi.co/docs/v2#resource-listspagination-section

Comment: I found a fix through fixing an issue that was in my HTML, forgot what it was at the moment. Also, discovered that the link for some Pokemon are broken. For example if you search for gengar off of the API website it will not be found.